# VSTS load tests not able to find assembly

Tags: visual-studio, binding, azure-devops, load-testing

I have written load tests that work fine if run locally. However when they are configured to run in cloud . I get following error

> Could not load File or assembly Newtonsoft.json 6.0.0 ...

I am using Visual studio 2017 15.7.4

Currently I am referring newtonsoft.json 11.0.2 in the project and here is my package.config file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <packages>
    <package id="Dapper" version="1.50.5" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.6" 
     targetFramework="net461" />
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net461" 
      />
      <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" 
      targetFramework="net461" />
       <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" 
      targetFramework="net461" />
         <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" 
           version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
          <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" 
           version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
          </packages>
```

Also here is the assembly binding that is added by default in the app.config after installation of nuget packages.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" 
  culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" 
      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" 
          culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" 
       publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

All the references are also marked as "CopyLocal" true.

Not sure what causes this.Any clues would be great.

Comment: It seems that one of your projects or assemblies/nuget packages is still referencing an older version of the `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package. Check if you're using different versions of that nuget package in the solution, and the references of every single project in the solution.

Comment: this is a standalone project and not dependant on any other projects in the solution.

Comment: There must be other dependency somewhere in that project that is still referencing v6.0.0

Comment: @MandarJogalekar Try to uninstall Newtonsoft.Json package, and reinstall it to see whether you can reproduce this issue. Also, try to run your project (don't copy the package) on another machine, to check whether you'll get the same error.

Comment: already uninstalled and installed newtonsoft.json. it doesnt work .
Also load tests are running on cloud so effectively my local machine just uploads the file there.right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Anyone who comes across this. It is weird but looks like.

System.Net.Http.Formatting (Installed using Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPI.Client 5.2.6)

and Newtonsoft.Json(11.0.2) arent compatible with each other.(When deployed to cloud on their own)

My code was breaking when I used HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync()

I simply ended up removing System.Net.Http.Formatting dll and used a longer version of code using httpclient.PostAsync and now it seems to work okay!